# Are there any spells that have Somatic components, but not Verbal components? (Material/Focus components irrelevant)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spell-components

Pretty straight forward Q. I suspect not, but I thought I'd open it up to the internet for comment.

Comment: Well, you say that. I don't think there are any in the PHB (just going from gut - I don't have the books to hand), I was wondering if it's a hard and fast rule that Somatic component necessarily implies Verbal. Any examples you want to give?

Comment: "Are there any?" can be answered with "sure, here's 3 random examples from 3 books to show they're quite common", right?

Comment: @Erik Hmmm, fair point - I didn't think of it that way.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHB alone, we have:

- [Gaseous Form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gaseousForm.htm)
- [Glibness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/glibness.htm)
- [Hide from Animals](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/hideFromAnimals.htm)
- [Mislead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mislead.htm)

Rest assured, there are plenty more in other books.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by the spells beginning with A in the Spell Compendium:

*Accelerated Movement*, *Aiming at the Target*, *Amorphous Form*, *Amplify* and *Animate Breath* all have Somatic components and no Verbal components. So, yes, there are spells like this, and no, somatic does not require verbal.

If you wanted to remove the verbal component from any spell, the *Silent Spell* metamagic feat is an option.